# PayPal Express Checkout: Notes not being returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using paypal_base.dll and Payflow_dotNET.dll

Have the following setup:

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestType.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.AllowNote = "1"
```

When checking out with PayPal Express Checkout (sandbox), the user can add notes. However, when the user submits an item, the notes field is `null`. Specifically:

1. Calling `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`
2. Populating `DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType`

However, on the response, the Note field located here:

```
DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails
```

is `null`. Is there some setting that I am missing? Is this not the field that corresponds to the order notes when using Paypal?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the settings in your paypal account settings.

Both in sandbox, and in production you must allow the account the ability to receive the payment.

The API does not override.